# мьютекс заблокирован несмотря на unlock

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2015

```
    class ThreadQ
    {
    public:
        ThreadQ() : t_(&ThreadQ::qwe, this){}

        ~ThreadQ(){ run_ = false; t_.join(); }


    private:
        void qwe()
        {
            cout << "qwe" << endl;

            boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock(mutex_);

            cout << "run=" << run_ << endl;

            while (run_)
            {
                cout << 33;

                lock.unlock();
                lock.lock();
            }
        }

        thread t_;
        boost::mutex mutex_;
        bool run_ = true;

    };


int main()
{
    ThreadQ t;

    system("pause");
}
```

В 80% случаев данный код при компиляции в visual studio 15 приводил к deadlock, В 10%  поток не запускался, ну и в 10% отрабатывал нормально...(полностью пересобрал проект несколько раз)

Однако после перезагрузки данные проблемы ушли(на полчаса), чем они могли быть вызваны? Windows 7

Версия boost: 1.60.0

Компилил буст:

```
b2 --stagedir=C:\boost_1_60_0cs_w address-model=32 -j4 --build-type=complete runtime-link=static define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0501
```

Версия компилятора: 14.00.23506.0

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, сочетание threads и mutex - чревато.

Comment: @PinkTux можно подробнее. Просто не могу представить для чего ещё могут понадобиться `mutex` кроме как для использования в `thread`.

Comment: А с `std::unique_lock/std::mutex` вместо бустовых как себя ведет программа?

Comment: Принципиальное отличие mutex от спинлока в сложности процесса. Спинлок - одноразовый, для простой блокировки конкретного объекта (см. теорию).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, std::mutex, на первом же lock выкинул исключение(Unhandled exception at 0x011AC297 in pipe.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.), я изменил переменную потока на указатель на поток и в конструкторе его уже создал, после этого ошибки прекратились, осталось разобраться почему со статикой это не работает...

Comment: @Kopkan, залочьте критичный код файловым локом.

Comment: @PinkTux всему своё место, для каких-то задач (относительно длительных) спинлок будет тяжелее мьютекса (см. теорию).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, в общем, перенес объявления thread в самый низ, после этого все стало отлично, забавно это конечно)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Порядок инициализации полей класса определяется порядком их декларации. В вашем случае сначала идет `thread` затем `mutex`. В списке инициализации конструктора у вас сразу запускается поток, исполняющий функцию `qwe`, в которой используется мьютекс. И время от времени получается так, что к моменту использования во втором потоке, мьютекс ещё не был инициализирован. От чего получаем фантомные глюки.